# Issue in Excel export using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a excel exporting system using laravel Maatwebsite v3 and vuejs for listing users near by postcode which is enter by admin.

Controller

```
public function export(Request $request)
{
    $file_name='frineds_'.date("d-m-Y h:i").'.csv';
    return Excel::download(new FriendExport($request['postcode'],$request['miles']), $file_name);
}
```

FriendImport.php

```
namespace App\Exports;
use App\Models\Friend;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class FriendExport implements FromCollection,WithHeadings
{
    function __construct($postcode,$miles) 
    {
      $this->postcode    = $postcode;
      $this->miles = $miles;
    }
    public function headings(): array
    { 
        return ['UNIQUE-ID','PHONE', 'POSTCODE'];
    }

public function collection()
{
    #get lat and log based on post coede
    $url = "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/".trim($this->postcode);
    $result_string = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($result_string, true);
    $latitude  = $result['result']['latitude'];
    $longitude = $result['result']['longitude'];
    $location_details_qry = DB::table("friends")
    ->select(
    'friends.unique_id',
    'friends.phone',
    'friends.postcode',
    DB::raw("6371 * acos(cos(radians('" . $latitude . "'))
    * cos(radians(friends.latitude))
    * cos(radians(friends.longitude) - radians('" . $longitude . "'))
    + sin(radians('" . $latitude . "'))
    * sin(radians(friends.latitude))) AS distance")
    ) ->havingRaw('distance<'.$this->miles)->orderBy('distance', 'asc');
    return $location_details_qry->get();
}
```

}

export.csv

[image]

I don't want the last column (distance) in export file. Help me how to solve this.

Comment: Use `WithMapping` traits for more : https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html

Comment: @Pradeep.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the rows. (https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html#mapping-rows)

To do so, your Class needs to implement WithMapping

```php
namespace App\Exports;
use App\Models\Friend;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
class FriendExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithMapping
{
    function __construct($postcode,$miles) 
    {
      $this->postcode    = $postcode;
      $this->miles = $miles;
    }
    public function headings(): array
    { 
        return ['UNIQUE-ID','PHONE', 'POSTCODE'];
    }

public function collection()
{
    #get lat and log based on post coede
    $url = "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/".trim($this->postcode);
    $result_string = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($result_string, true);
    $latitude  = $result['result']['latitude'];
    $longitude = $result['result']['longitude'];
    $location_details_qry = DB::table("friends")
    ->select(
    'friends.unique_id',
    'friends.phone',
    'friends.postcode',
    DB::raw("6371 * acos(cos(radians('" . $latitude . "'))
    * cos(radians(friends.latitude))
    * cos(radians(friends.longitude) - radians('" . $longitude . "'))
    + sin(radians('" . $latitude . "'))
    * sin(radians(friends.latitude))) AS distance")
    ) ->havingRaw('distance<'.$this->miles)->orderBy('distance', 'asc');
    return $location_details_qry->get();
}

public function map($row): array
{
    return [
        $row->unique_id,
        $row->phone,
        $row->postcode
    ];
}
```

Comment: Its working. Thank you. Can you just a look 3rd row of my excel. Phone number is listing excel format. Do i need to do something.?

Comment: Yup, I see it. I had a similar problem in the past. You can use column formatting to get rid of it.

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html#formatting-columns

Comment: Also, you might be able to just cast it when you map it... However I am not sure about this, but you can try: (string)$row->phone, – what is sure that column formatting does the trick. :)